# Comparing two queries while executing

Tags: mysql

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECTcom_jobcard.job_card_num,process.process_name,employee.emp_name,employee.emp_code ,SUM(worked_qty) FROMcom_jobcard
INNER JOIN timer_completed ON timer_completed.job_card_id = com_jobcard.id 
INNER JOIN process ON process.id = timer_completed.process_id 
INNER JOIN employee ON employee.id = timer_completed.employee_id
AND job_card_id = ( SELECT id FROM com_jobcard WHERE job_card_num =  'JCID-1271742')
GROUP BY process.process_name,employee.emp_name ");

$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT com_jobcard.job_card_num,process.process_name,employee.emp_name,employee.emp_code,SUM(qc.rework_qty),qc.report_date,qc.id FROM qc 
INNER JOIN com_jobcard ON qc.job_card_id = com_jobcard.id
INNER JOIN process ON process.id = qc.process_id
INNER JOIN qc_employees ON qc_employees.qc_id = qc.id
INNER JOIN employee ON employee.id = qc_employees.employee_id
AND qc_employees.qc_id = (SELECT qc.id
FROM qc
INNER JOIN com_jobcard ON qc.job_card_id = com_jobcard.id
AND com_jobcard.job_card_num =  'JCID-1271742')
GROUP BY process.process_name,employee.emp_name");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1);
if( ($row[1] == $row1[1]) && ($row[3] == $row1[3] ))
{
echo $row1[0] .$row1[1]  .$row1[2] .$row1[3] .$row1[4];
}
}
```

Dear friends I am executing 2 queries simultaneously but I would like to compare both the result sets when `$row[1] == $row1[1]) && ($row[3] == $row1[3]` the condition is satisfied then it has to return the result but as if now it returns nothing could any one suggest me how to compare the result set of both the queries , Instead of using IF I have also used While statement , though I didn't recieve the result .
Please help me!
Thank you!

Comment: Are you comparing rows from two results?

Comment: @ArunKrish No the values returned in both the queries

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this

```
$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
 while($row1) {
   if( ($row['process_name'] == $row1['process_name']) && ($row['emp_name'] == $row1['emp_name'] ))
    {
      echo $row1['job_card_num'] .$row1['process_name']  .$row1['emp_name'] .$row1['emp_code'] .$row1['sum_qty'];
    }
 }
}
```

Because you have used $row[1] $row1[1] which has no value.
 I ahev used alias vakue for SUM(qc.rework_qty) in your query as sum_qty